# JavaScript, fancybox gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css, fancybox, gallery

Hello, I have a problem with creating dynamics gallery using JS:

- I don't know how to get my gallery with JS - "gallery-pk-1-1"

  ```
  <a data-fancybox="gallery-pk-1-1" href="data/images/sertificate/PARK TOWER/1 rooms/1 type/main.jpg" data-caption="">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="data/images/sertificate/PARK TOWER/1 rooms/1 type/main.jpg" alt="" style="height: auto">
  </a>
  ```
- I don't know how to add images in gallery with JS
- Open fancy gallery on click (it's easy if I just add more images using code upper, but my site is loading slow because have many images - that's why I want to create gallery only when user clicks on main image)
- I want to create 1 JS function for 1 gallery, where I will add images one by one, because I haven't any normal DB, just images with different names.
- Code of my gallery:

  ```
  JS:
    <script id="gallery" type="text/javascript">
      $.fancybox.open({
          src  : 'link-to-your-page.html',
          type : 'iframe',
          opts : {
              afterShow : function( instance, current ) {
                  console.info( 'done!' );
              }
          }
      });
    </script>
  HTML:
    <a data-fancybox="gallery-pk-1-1" href="data/images/sertificate/PARK TOWER/1 rooms/1 type/render/1.jpg" data-caption="">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="data/images/sertificate/PARK TOWER/1 rooms/1 type/render/1.jpg" alt="" style="height: auto">
    </a>
    <a data-fancybox="gallery-pk-1-1" href="data/images/sertificate/PARK TOWER/1 rooms/1 type/render/2.jpg" data-caption="">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="data/images/sertificate/PARK TOWER/1 rooms/1 type/render/2.jpg" alt="" style="height: auto">
    </a>
  ...
  ```

Answer (score 0):

So, basically, you just want to display one preview image for each gallery? You could just create hidden links for additional images, like so

```
<a href="https://source.unsplash.com/Ai2TRdvI6gM/1500x1000" data-fancybox="images-preview" 
     data-width="1500" data-height="1000"
     data-thumb="https://source.unsplash.com/Ai2TRdvI6gM/240x160"></a>
```

See this demo https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/EeqJPG?editors=1000 (look for "Gallery with one preview image").

Alternatively, you could create custom click event on your preview image where you would start fancybox using API:

```
$.fancybox.open([
    {
        src  : '1_b.jpg',
        opts : {
            caption : 'First caption',
            thumb   : '1_s.jpg'
        }
    },
    {
        src  : '2_b.jpg',
        opts : {
            caption : 'Second caption',
            thumb   : '2_s.jpg'
        }
    }
], {
    loop : false
});
```

Comment: {
            src  : 'data/images/sertificate/PARK TOWER/1 rooms/1 type/main.jpg',
            opts : {
                caption : 'First caption',
                thumb   : 'data/images/sertificate/PARK TOWER/1 rooms/1 type/main.jpg'
            }
        },

Comment: Sorry, but I could not understand your comment. And it is almost impossible to help without live page/demo.

Comment: It work when I test in codepen.io, but doesn't work when test in my site :(

Comment: It is so simple to setup and to use fancybox that I literally have no idea what could be the cause of your issue. It just works. If you do not want to share your page url publicly, you can DM on twitter, chat on https://gitter.im/fancyapps/fancybox or drop email to info at fancyapps dot com

Comment: https://codepen.io/krip4yk-main-the-looper/pen/zYYJbKp?editors=1011

Comment: Find answer - it work only when adress without spaces " "

Comment: Hmm, yes, sorry about that; see https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-uri